# Union-Find implementation does not update parent tags

Tags: rust, union-find

I'm trying to create some sets of `String`s and then merge some of these sets so that they have the same tag (of type `usize`). Once I initialize the map, I start adding strings:

```
self.clusters.make_set("a");
self.clusters.make_set("b");
```

When I call `self.clusters.find("a")` and `self.clusters.find("b")`, different values are returned, which is fine because I haven't merged the sets yet. Then I call the following method to merge two sets

```
let _ = self.clusters.union("a", "b");
```

If I call `self.clusters.find("a")` and `self.clusters.find("b")` now, I get the same value. However, when I call the `finalize()` method and try to iterate through the map, the original tags are returned, as if I never merged the sets.

```
self.clusters.finalize();

for (address, tag) in &self.clusters.map {
    self.clusterizer_writer.write_all(format!("{};{}\n", address, 
    self.clusters.parent[*tag]).as_bytes()).unwrap();
}

// to output all keys with the same tag as a list. 
let a: Vec<(usize, Vec<String>)> = {
    let mut x = HashMap::new();
    for (k, v) in self.clusters.map.clone() {
        x.entry(v).or_insert_with(Vec::new).push(k)
    }
    x.into_iter().collect()
};
```

I can't figure out why this is the case, but I'm relatively new to Rust; maybe its an issue with pointers?

Instead of "a" and "b", I'm actually using something like `utils::arr_to_hex(&input.outpoint.txid)` of type `String`.

This is the Rust implementation of the Union-Find algorithm that I am using:

```
/// Tarjan's Union-Find data structure.
#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable)]
pub struct DisjointSet<T: Clone + Hash + Eq> {
    set_size: usize,
    parent: Vec<usize>,
    rank: Vec<usize>,
    map: HashMap<T, usize>, // Each T entry is mapped onto a usize tag.
}

impl<T> DisjointSet<T>
where
    T: Clone + Hash + Eq,
{
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        const CAPACITY: usize = 1000000;
        DisjointSet {
            set_size: 0,
            parent: Vec::with_capacity(CAPACITY),
            rank: Vec::with_capacity(CAPACITY),
            map: HashMap::with_capacity(CAPACITY),
        }
    }

    pub fn make_set(&mut self, x: T) {
        if self.map.contains_key(&x) {
            return;
        }

        let len = &mut self.set_size;
        self.map.insert(x, *len);
        self.parent.push(*len);
        self.rank.push(0);

        *len += 1;
    }

    /// Returns Some(num), num is the tag of subset in which x is.
    /// If x is not in the data structure, it returns None.
    pub fn find(&mut self, x: T) -> Option<usize> {
        let pos: usize;
        match self.map.get(&x) {
            Some(p) => {
                pos = *p;
            }
            None => return None,
        }

        let ret = DisjointSet::<T>::find_internal(&mut self.parent, pos);
        Some(ret)
    }

    /// Implements path compression.
    fn find_internal(p: &mut Vec<usize>, n: usize) -> usize {
        if p[n] != n {
            let parent = p[n];
            p[n] = DisjointSet::<T>::find_internal(p, parent);
            p[n]
        } else {
            n
        }
    }

    /// Union the subsets to which x and y belong.
    /// If it returns Ok<u32>, it is the tag for unified subset.
    /// If it returns Err(), at least one of x and y is not in the disjoint-set.
    pub fn union(&mut self, x: T, y: T) -> Result<usize, ()> {
        let x_root;
        let y_root;
        let x_rank;
        let y_rank;
        match self.find(x) {
            Some(x_r) => {
                x_root = x_r;
                x_rank = self.rank[x_root];
            }
            None => {
                return Err(());
            }
        }

        match self.find(y) {
            Some(y_r) => {
                y_root = y_r;
                y_rank = self.rank[y_root];
            }
            None => {
                return Err(());
            }
        }

        // Implements union-by-rank optimization.
        if x_root == y_root {
            return Ok(x_root);
        }

        if x_rank > y_rank {
            self.parent[y_root] = x_root;
            return Ok(x_root);
        } else {
            self.parent[x_root] = y_root;
            if x_rank == y_rank {
                self.rank[y_root] += 1;
            }
            return Ok(y_root);
        }
    }

    /// Forces all laziness, updating every tag.
    pub fn finalize(&mut self) {
        for i in 0..self.set_size {
            DisjointSet::<T>::find_internal(&mut self.parent, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere this code updates the `map` field after the initial insertion. `find_internal` updates `parent`, but this is not going to help if your intent is to iterate over `map` directly. Perhaps `finalize` needs to rewrite the index in `map` for each value to the index returned from `find_internal` inside of the loop over all values. Or to ask another debugging question, do you get the correct information after calling `finalize` if you call `find` rather than iterating over the `map`? Perhaps you want to implement iteration as a trait of `DisjointSet` itself using `find_internal`?

Comment: Thanks for these tips. I'm new to rust so I might have misunderstood, but I replaced self.clusters.parent[*tag] with self.clusters.find(address.clone()) and I get the same result.

Comment: I'd suggest debugging this by printing out values at various points since I don't think the error is due to unique features of Rust. E.g. if you call `self.clusters.find("a")` and `self.clusters.find("b")` immediately after the call to `finalize` do they return the same thing they did before the call? Your second comment here applies to the serialization loop I think. I was referring to this line `for (k, v) in self.clusters.map.clone()`. Is the serialization loop supposed to replace the values in `map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just not extracting the information out of your `DisjointSet` struct correctly.

I got [sniped](https://xkcd.com/356/) by this and implemented union find.  First, with a basic usize implemention:

```
pub struct UnionFinderImpl {
    parent: Vec<usize>,
}
```

Then with a wrapper for more generic types:

```
pub struct UnionFinder<T: Hash> {
    rev: Vec<Rc<T>>,
    fwd: HashMap<Rc<T>, usize>,
    uf: UnionFinderImpl,
}
```

Both structs implement a `groups()` method that returns a `Vec<Vec<>>` of groups.  `Clone` isn't required because I used `Rc`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e9c9ab23cb9136563724f2db24de56dc&version=stable)

Comment: very good code, thanks for providing test cases. How could I implement the find_parent method for a generic type?

Comment: Use `fwd` to find the `usize` corresponding to your `T`, use `uf.find_parent()` to find the parent `usize`, then use `rev` to map from the parent `usize` back to an `Rc<T>`.